# How to use releaseImplementation in a library

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am using Android Studio 3.0 with the updated gradle plugin.

I need to use the `releaseImplementation` keyword in my `build.gradle` file as I only want the library specified (`ACRA`) to be built in release. The reason I only want to build ACRA in release is that I've read that Android Studio instant run does not work well with ACRA.

```
releaseImplementation 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.2'
```

The problem is, however, that it's a library so I also need to use the `api` key so I can transitively export in apis to the modules using the library.

```
api 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.2'
```

Is it possible to use both keywords or is there a composite keyword to use?

```
releaseImplementation 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.2'
api 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.2'
```

Comment: What is the sense?

Comment: How do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android Studio 3.0 and newer, the Android Gradle Plugin supports the new Java Library plugin configurations that allow more granular control of dependencies.

As described [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration), the new Gradle Dependency configurations are available for flavor- or build-type-specific dependencies.
If you wish to use the `api` dependency configuration for the `release` build Type, you would add the following:

`releaseApi 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.2'`

This is the "composite keyword" that you are describing.  No additional dependency needs to be specified.